# Aligning rows of table layout used as cards

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm making an html email template, it's my first time, I have a design to respect. I'm really struggling with the table layout.
I have this layout.
[image]
Like you see, when the text is big, it makes the rows not aligned.
What changes I should make to fix this?
Here's my code of only two cards:

```html
<table class="table_scale" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate;
                                border-spacing: 30px;
                                *border-collapse: expression('separate', cellSpacing='30px');">
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #fff; padding: 20px; border-radius: 20px;">
      <table style="border-collapse: separate;border-spacing: 0 10px;">
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color:  #0C49F6; font-style: normal;
                                                    font-weight: 500;
                                                    font-size: 25px;
                                                    color: #FFFFFF; padding: 15px 25px; border-radius: 15px;
                                                    text-align: center;">
            -34% de réduction
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-style: normal;
                                                    font-weight: 700;
                                                    font-size: 20px;
                                                    color: #1B0F66;">
            E-mail marketing
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-style: normal;
                                                    font-weight: 400;
                                                    font-size: 19px;
                                                    color: #8C8A8A;">
            Crée votre Site Web personnalisé
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td style="background-color: #fff; padding: 20px; border-radius: 20px;">
      <table style="border-collapse: separate;border-spacing: 0 10px;">
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color:  #0C49F6; font-style: normal;
                                                    font-weight: 500;
                                                    font-size: 25px;
                                                    color: #FFFFFF; padding: 15px 25px; border-radius: 15px;
                                                    text-align: center;">
            -33% de réduction
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-style: normal;
                                                    font-weight: 700;
                                                    font-size: 20px;
                                                    color: #1B0F66;">
            Facebook Ads
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-style: normal;
                                                    font-weight: 400;
                                                    font-size: 19px;
                                                    color: #8C8A8A;">
            Lancer votre publicité sur Facebook & Instagram
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Add 50% width into td

Comment: Are you asking about the width of the columns (that appears to be an issue in your snippet), or about the vertical alignment of the blue bars? For the latter, add `vertical-align: top;` to the table cells.

Answer (score 0):

Changes done:

- td made 50% width
- Tables made 100% width

```html
<table class="table_scale" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: separate;
                                border-spacing: 30px;
                                *border-collapse: expression('separate', cellSpacing='30px');">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" valign="top" style="background-color: #fff; padding: 20px; border-radius: 20px;">
      <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: separate;border-spacing: 0 10px;">
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color:  #0C49F6; font-style: normal;
                                                    font-weight: 500;
                                                    font-size: 25px;
                                                    color: #FFFFFF; padding: 15px 25px; border-radius: 15px;
                                                    text-align: center;">
            -34% de réduction
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-style: normal;
                                                    font-weight: 700;
                                                    font-size: 20px;
                                                    color: #1B0F66;">
            E-mail marketing
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-style: normal;
                                                    font-weight: 400;
                                                    font-size: 19px;
                                                    color: #8C8A8A;">
            Crée votre Site Web personnalisé
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td width="50%" style="background-color: #fff; padding: 20px; border-radius: 20px;">
      <table width="100%" style="border-collapse: separate;border-spacing: 0 10px;">
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color:  #0C49F6; font-style: normal;
                                                    font-weight: 500;
                                                    font-size: 25px;
                                                    color: #FFFFFF; padding: 15px 25px; border-radius: 15px;
                                                    text-align: center;">
            -33% de réduction
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-style: normal;
                                                    font-weight: 700;
                                                    font-size: 20px;
                                                    color: #1B0F66;">
            Facebook Ads
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="font-style: normal;
                                                    font-weight: 400;
                                                    font-size: 19px;
                                                    color: #8C8A8A;">
            Lancer votre publicité sur Facebook & Instagram
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```